# Trying to build an API route in express for my database interactions... getting a 404

Tags: json, node.js, express

I have an express route that looks like this:

```
app.post('/api/:type/*/*/*', apiRoute.api);
```

in my route file I have:

```
exports.api = function(req, res) {
    var type = req.params.type;
    var entity  = req.params['0'];
    var field  = req.params['1'];
    var params = req.params['2'];

    switch (type)
    {
        case "get":
               return {'entity' : entity, 'field' : field, 'params' : params}
            break;

        case "post":

            break;
    }
}
```

however when I go to

```
http://localhost:3000/api/get/industry/id/5
```

I get Cannot GET /api/get/industry/id/5

What am I doing wrong and what do I have to do to get it to return json?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a route for POST, and you're accessing it with a GET. If all you want to do is return some data from the server, you should define the route with GET:

```
app.get('/api/:type/*/*/*', apiRoute.api);
```

Otherwise, you should issue a POST request from the client to use the POST route you defined.

Comment: Can I define the same routes for both get and post?

Comment: AFAIK, yes. The method on the request should determine which of your routes will be called.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what else could be wrong. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app.route()` as a shortcut to the Router to define multiple requests on a route. Please see the sample below that use express 4

```
var express =  require('express');
var app     =  express();
var port    =  process.env.PORT || 8080;

// ROUTES

var router = express.Router();

// apply the routes to our application
app.use('/', router);

// api routes
app.route('/api/:type/*/*/*')

    .get(function(req, res) {
        var type = req.params.type;
        var entity  = req.params['0'];
        var field  = req.params['1'];
        var params = req.params['2'];

        res.json({'entity' : entity, 'field' : field, 'params' : params});  
    })

    .post(function(req, res) {
        res.send('code to process post request goes here!');
    });

    // START THE SERVER     
    app.listen(port);
    console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
```

Hopes this solves your problem..